# Why do mailing list replies sometimes ignore my importance filters?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, priority-inbox

I have 3 filters for importance labelling in my Priority Inbox:

> - Matches: **from:(-me) to:(-me)**
>
>   - Do this: Never mark it as important
> - Matches: **from:me to:me**
>
>   - Do this: Never mark it as important
> - Matches: **from:(-me) to:me**
>
>   - Do this: Apply label "@", Mark it as important

I have other filters after these that apply labels only.

In my Inbox settings, I have chosen "Don't use my past actions to predict which messages are important" and "Don't override filters".

Today I once again have a large number of messages in my Priority Inbox which do not have the "@" label, yet have been marked as important. When I hover over the Importance marker on any of these messages, it reads "Important according to our magic sauce."

I thought I "disabled the magic sauce", and I've confirmed these conversations match my first filter above and do not match my third filter.

It does seem to happen only when one person sends a message to a mailing list, and another person replies; though I'm not entirely sure.

How do I fix this? (Alternatively, is there some other solution to make Priority Inbox "everything addressed to me" and nothing else?)